# Composer package installation order

Tags: php, composer-php

Say I have `package-a` and `package-b`. I want to install these in a particular order, `package-a` to install first, then `package-b`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scenario you are describing is effectively a dependency. Package B depends on Package A to be installed. So make sure that package B depends on package A.

Other than that, no guarantees are given for order.